# Relation of spring constant with mean radius of spring

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, spring

My teacher says that spring constant depends on its radius. I tried to understand it, and checked many questions in this site and other sites. All of them say that spring constant depends on number of windings and material of spring. But it doesn't say anything about its radius. Is it true? If yes, what is the radius meant by him? Is it the radius of winding or radius of string on which the spring made?

Comment: This http://www.amesweb.info/MechanicalSprings/CompressionSpringForcedBasedDesign.aspx might help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stiffness $k$ of a coil spring can be expresses as:
$$k=\frac{E\,d^4}{16\,(1+\nu)\,(D-d)^3\,n}$$

Where $E$ is the modulus of elasticity of the material, $d$ is the diameter of the wire used in the coil, $\nu$ is the poisons ratio of the material, $D$ is the outer diameter of the coil, and $n$ is the number of wraps in the coil.

Now $\frac{D-d}2$ is equal to the mean radius of the coil ie. the distance from the center of the coil to the middle of the wire. So the equation could be rewritten as:

$$k=\frac{E\,r^4}{8\,(1+\nu)\,{r_{mean}}^3\,n}$$

Where $r$ is the radius of the wire and $r_{mean}$ is the mean radius of the coil.

Answer (score 1):

You probably experienced that a thick sheet or bar of material is more rigid than a thin one : cross section count. You will find the theory and complete formula getting the spring "constant" [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_(device)#Theory) (it is pretty involved).